Openshift - Find Deployments with only one Pod
I have a big cluster on Openshift Platform. I want to find all the projects and deployments that have only one pod. Is there a command for that? How can I make a list of all the namespaces and deployments with only one pod?

I got this code and it seems to be working.
oc get deployments --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{.metadata.namespace} {.metadata.name} {.spec.replicas}{"\n"}{end}' | awk '$3 == 1 {print $1, $2}'

